# What tool do you prefer for interface design?

Tags: interface-design, tools

I primarily designs interfaces for web based applications. I prefer to use Illustrator. I find that it's quick and flexible for designing interfaces. Working with flexible artboards and vector based objects is useful for responsive design. I have also used Photoshop and Sketch, but have found illustrator to be the most versatile for designing responsive interfaces.

But it seems like most people are using Sketch and Photoshop for interface design and I feel like maybe I'm missing out on something. I'm always looking to improve my workflow and I am curious what others are using and why.

So, what tool do you prefer for interface design and why do you prefer it?

Comment: I think it is a valid question. Interesting one actually :o(

Comment: @Rafael It may be an interesting question but the tools used are at ones discretion, the software suggested ALWAYS changes over time so the answer scope could change within a year or so and this type of question is gold to spammer services.

Comment: My favorite tool is the intern. While I take a long lunch.